# Можно ли написать парсер для сайта на который подгружается информация от Google Расширения?

Tags: python

Недавно начал изучать Python , конкретнее парсер, и столкнулся с такой проблемой, то что информацию которое подгружает Расширение не "Парсится". Можно ли это как-то изменить, если да, то как.

Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: "Расширение" - имеется ввиду расширение браузера?

Comment: Посмотрите примеры работы selenium - это средства управления браузером. То есть вы получаете итоговую страницу со всем выполненным js-кодом.

Comment: Общий ответ: Да, можно. Конкретно: всё зависит от Вашего конкретного случая. Какой сайт, какое расширение, как расширение работает и т.д.